# Getting Array with values from an array of NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have an array with 4 Dictionaries with key @"preference" like as follows

```
 (
        {
          preference = Nose;
        },

        {
          preference = "Heart rate";
        },

        {
          preference = Glucose;
        },

        {
          preference = Food;
        }
)
```

Now i want to retrieve an  array for these dictionary values like"

```
 (
    Nose, Heart rate,  Glucose,  Food
 )
```

How s'd i get it.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 24):

A one-liner:

```
NSArray *resultingArray = [arrayOfDictionaries valueForKeyPath:@"preference"];
```

Comment: You might get marginally better performance in this case by using `-valueForKey:`

Answer (score 9):

Try it:

```
NSArray *result = [dictionaryObject valueForKeyPath:@"preference"];
```

It'll solve your Problem

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this:

```
NSMutableArray *collectedValues = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:array.count];

for (NSDictionary *dict in array) {
    NSString *value = [dict objectForKey:@"preference"];
    if (value) {
        [collectedValues addObject:value];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with this code:
myArray is your first array
mySecondArray is the array you have in the end

```
 NSMutableArray *mySecondArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        for (int i = 0; i < [myArray count] ; i++)
        {
            NSDictionary *tempDict = [myArray objectForIndex:i];
            [mySecondArray addObject:[tempDict objectForKey@"preference"]];


        }
```